# Unable to post message on Teams using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-teams, graph-api, postman, python

I am trying to post message on a teams channel but I am not able to do that.
I have got the required permissions also - Teamwork.Migrate.All.
The following code snippet is being used:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teams-id}/channels/{channel -id}}/messages"

payload = json.dumps({
  "body": {
    "content": "Hello World"
  }
})
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer <access-token>',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Following error is being generated:

> "error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"Message POST is allowed in
> application-only context only for import purposes}

Need help resolving the issue

Comment: Have you approved API access to Microsoft Graph your code such as  `const msalRequest = {
    scopes: [
        'Chat.Create',
        'Chat.ReadWrite',
        'ChatMessage.Send',
        'Chat.ReadWrite',
        'User.ReadBasic.All',
        'Directory.Read.All',
        'Directory.AccessAsUser.All',
    ]
  }` See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/getting-started-with-graph-api-and-teams/

Comment: yes I have these requests